# How to loop over multiple DataFrames and produce multiple list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some difficulties to create multiple lists using pandas from a list of multiple dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')   
...
dfN = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')

dfs = [df1, df2, ..., dfN]
```

So far, I am able to convert each dataframe into a list by `df1 = df1.values.tolist()`. Since I have multiple data frames, I would like to convert each dataframe into a list with a loop.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehensions:

```
dfs = [i.values.tolist() for i in dfs]
```

Answer (score 1):

same as you are storing dataframes?

```
lists = []
for df in dfs:
    temp_list = df.values.tolist()
    lists.append(temp_list)
```

This will give you a list of lists. Each list within will be values from a dataframe. Or did I understand the question incorrectly?

Edit: If you wish to name each list, then you can use a dictionary instead? Would be better than trying to create thousands of variables dynamically.

```
dict_of_lists = {}
for index, df in enumerate(dfs):
    listname = "list" + str(index)
    dict_of_lists[listname] = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you! What I need is to store each list in lists as a seperate list. I hope I'm expressing myself clearly.

Comment: I have added new code. Maybe this will allow you to summon each list by name(dict key). It will also help you to store all the lists in one variable instead of creating thousands of variables for as many dfs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That's a valid point avoiding multiple variables. My initial idea was to overwrite each data frame with its corresponding df. Suppose I overwrite `df1 = df1.values.tolist()` and so on. The result is that I am simply overwriting each dataframe. In this case I can use them later in other application and it is easer for me to read the code when I can employ each dataframe by its name (such as `sale, turnover for df1 and df2..`) instead of using `dict_of_lists['list0']` to get df1.

Answer (score 1):

use `pd.concat` to join all dataframes to one big dataframe

```
df_all = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1)

df_all.values.tolist()
```